# "value cannot be null. parameter name current"  when trying to  drag button

Tags: wpf

I have couple of buttons on a WPF Window. When I try to drag them I get an following error in dialog box:

> value cannot be null. parameter name current

I do not know how to handle it.

Here is my code:

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Style="{DynamicResource MajourColoumnWidth}"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Style="{DynamicResource MinourColoumnWidth}"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Name="ClinicalDetailsGrid1" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition  Style="{DynamicResource RowHeight1}"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
           <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Content="Save" Name="btnSave" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="100" Height="20"/>
        <Button Content="Bill Payment" Name="btnSave1" Grid.Row="0" 
                Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                Width="100" Height="20"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you show us any Code Behind related to `btnSave` and `btnSave1`?

Comment: There is no code behind added yet. I am just creating a prototype.

Comment: What do you mean when you try to drag them? In the designer? Or are you doing something with drag in the real app?

Comment: @Tim - Yes, In the designer. I just wanna dragg them to another column, but when i try to, One javascript type dialog box opens and gives above error :-(

Comment: This may seem stupid - but how about just hand-editing the XAML?

Comment: @Goblin : I used the same approach, when i neither get the explanation nor a way to solve the error. But still I  would love to know the reason behind this message/error ??

Comment: I have found the XAML editor in Visual Studio to be too buggy to be actually usable (at least it was when WPF was just introduced) that I've forced myself to avoid it... also, I like the control of hand-crafting the XAML - and at least with R# it is actually faster (for me) than the toolbox.

Comment: I'd also suggest to not(!) use the VS Designer for designing your WPF UI. Some things can't be accomplished with it and others are solved too simple. e.g. dragging an element around just changes the margin, which is not always correct. Better use the direct xaml markup editor and try to use Layout Panels wherever possible to structure your UI.
see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152.aspx

PS: Copied your markup and I could drag the buttons. Perhaps the issue comes from the Dynamic Resource Styles? I'd remove them and try again.